# Creating a reverse manager hierarchy in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns, employee ID and Supervisor ID, in a format below:

| Employee ID | Supervisor ID |
| --- | --- |
| 11111 | 22222 |
| 22222 | 33333 |
| 33333 | 44444 |
| 44444 | 55555 |
| 55555 |  |

Through VLOOKUPs or XLOOKUPs I can create a hierarchy that tell me who the top level manager is, but the top level manager doesn't always line up.

| Employee ID | Supervisor ID | Supervisor+1 ID | Supervisor+2 ID | Supervisor+3 ID | Supervisor+4 ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 22222 | 33333 | 44444 | 55555 |  |
| 22222 | 33333 | 44444 | 55555 |  |  |

I am wanting to create a reverse hierarchy in Excel.

| Employee ID | Supervisor+4 ID | Supervisor+3 ID | Supervisor+2 ID | Supervisor+1 ID | Supervisor ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 55555 | 44444 | 33333 | 22222 |  |
| 22222 | 55555 | 44444 | 33333 |  |  |

I read this article https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Reverse-Company-Hierarchy/td-p/1545861 where OP said they are able to complete it with MATCH and INDEX functions. But after reading about MATCH and INDEX functions, I am still not understanding. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Are there always max. 4 Supervisor-level?

Comment: Your reverse hierarchy doesn’t look right to me.  Your table labels the highest manager each person’s “supervisor + 4” but if you are employee ID 22222 as shown, then employee 55555 is your highest level sup, but is *not* your sup+4.  They are your sup+3.  I think a reverse hierarchy would actually be “top dog”, “top dog-1”, “top dog-2”, etc.

Comment: Can't you simply switch the columns? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a lambda like this:

```
=LAMBDA(employee,empRange,bossRange,LET(boss,XLOOKUP(employee,empRange,bossRange,""),IF(boss="","",getBoss(boss,empRange,bossRange)&"|"&boss)))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've never used a lambda or let function before, so this is exciting! If I understand the lambda function correctly, "employee" = employee ID (single cell in column A), empRange is column A, bossRange is column B, "boss" = supervisor ID (single cell in column B that corresponds with column A). What does "getBoss" refer to? It's throwing an error when I replace the names with those values...

Comment: Oh wait, after reading some more on LAMBDAs and having to name them, I got it to work! What a cool function! Will definitely learn how to use them for other things! Thanks!

Comment: Glad it was useful. 'Raw' lambda's aren't everyone's cup of tea - they are more often used with helper functions like Map, Scan, Byrow and Bycol. I think they do have their place, but their main downside is that as far as I know there is no way to step through them to debug them.

Comment: Wait, there is the Advanced Formula Environment https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/garage/profiles/advanced-formula-environment-a-microsoft-garage-project/ ,but it's an add-on.